# How to get the path of my DFP ad unit for Angular 5+

Tags: angular, ads, google-dfp

I am following this tutorial https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-dfp

```
<dfp-ad adUnit="/path-to-my/ad-unit" responsive (afterRefresh)="refreshed($event)">
  <dfp-size [width]="320" [height]="50"></dfp-size>
  <dfp-responsive [viewport]="[800,0]" [adSizes]="[[728,90],[600,300]]"></dfp-responsive>
  <dfp-responsive [viewWidth]="1024">
    <dfp-size [width]="970" [height]="90"></dfp-size>
    <dfp-size [width]="1024" [height]="90"></dfp-size>
  </dfp-responsive>
  <dfp-targeting key="food" [value]="['chicken','meatballs']"></dfp-targeting>
</dfp-ad>
```

I just want to know `adUnit="/path-to-my/ad-unit"` what does this path contains and from where I will get this path?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use this module, but I suppose that it corresponds to an underlying GPT call `defineSlot`:

> **adUnitPath**: Full path of the ad unit with the network code and unit code.

```
googletag.defineSlot('/1234567/sports', [728, 90], 'div-1');
```

https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.defineSlot

Find your network code in your Google Ad Manager console: https://admanager.google.com/1234567#admin/networkSettings (or in your GAM URL) and concatenate the targeted adUnit `code` which can be found by selecting and adUnit in your GAM: https://admanager.google.com/1234567#inventory/inventory/.

In the example above, the network ID is `1234567` and the targeted adUnit code is `sports`, which, formatted as a "path" results in `/1234567/sports`.

The example code demonstrates the result here: https://github.com/atwwei/ngx-dfp/blob/master/src/app/page/page.component.html#L14